# Parse Int image array to Byte array in Android fails when using BitmapFactory

Tags: android, swift, kotlin

Try to use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` to generate Bitmap and assign into ImageView.

Original file is a Int String like the following "77 78 255 0 ..."

**Following code is for converting from String to ByteArray:**

```
fun serialize(imageDataString: String): ByteArray {
    val imageDataArray = imageDataString.split(" ").toTypedArray()
    val bDataArray = ByteArray(imageDataArray.size)
    for (i in imageDataArray.indices) {
        val optionalIntValue = imageDataArray[i].toIntOrNull()
        if(optionalIntValue != null) {
            bDataArray[i] = optionalIntValue.toByte()
        }
    }
    return bDataArray
}
```

But it did not work and show null after apply converted byteArray to `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`

**Working fine by applying similar logic in IOS**

```
let array = imageData.description.split(separator: " ")                                
var imageBytes : [UInt8] = []                
array.forEach({ (substringData) in                    
   let stringData = String(substringData)                    
   if let intData = UInt8(stringData) {                        
       imageBytes.append(intData)                    
   }                
})
                
let parsedImageData = NSData(bytes: imageBytes, length: imageBytes.count)
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the function? Looks like the input string has a problem, otherwise the function looks fine.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Thanks for the reply. The input string works fine when it parsed on IOS. :( I also checked spaces... Does android has some kind of Bitmap size limitation? I specified 150 x 150.

Comment: Do you have an example valid string we can try?